# How to include JSON files in a NuGet package (nupkg)?

Tags: nuget-package

I have been following a previous SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73248959/add-cs-and-json-files-into-a-multi-platform-nuget-package). So I ended up writing in my csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Data\Dicts\*.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
      <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
      <BuildAction>Content</BuildAction>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>contentFiles/any/any/Json;content/Json</PackagePath>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

However it seems it is being installed into two folders at the same time:

[image]

What did I misunderstood ?

Thanks